Role of を in 地面を引きずる

マントが地面を引きずるような音だった。  (Harry Potter, Japanese TL)
It sounded like a cloak trailing along the ground. (English version)

Is this sentence natural? I'm puzzled about the 地面を引きずる part. I know that 引きずる is a transitive verb. I've seen it used in 足を引きずる, for example, where 足 makes sense as the object of the verb. However, I interpret 地面を引きずる to mean that the ground is being pulled along by the cloak. This could work. We could picture this as the top layer of dirt being displaced and causing the sound, but is that really the correct mental image?
Another thought was that this を could be the one that denotes passage through somewhere/something e.g. 公園を歩く. I think I'd be happier with this interpretation.

This 引きずる (引き擦る) is used as a plain transitive verb. を meaning "through/across" is not relevant (the described action doesn't involve traveling a long distance).
I personally have never found this usage unnatural. You can find many examples of カーテンが床を引き擦る, ズボンの裾が地面を引き擦る and so on online. This English-Japanese dictionary uses 地面を引きずる in the definition of "drag". Many verbs have multiple usages, so just because we say 足を引き摺る based on one usage doesn't mean we cannot say 地面を引き摺る based on another usage. If I understand correctly, "drag" in English also has two usages, and "Her dress dragged on the floor" is a valid sentence.
However, some people argue that 地面を引きずる is incorrect because such usage is not directly listed in the dictionary they checked, so this may not be as universally accepted as I initially thought. Just because I don't feel any discomfort doesn't necessarily mean that everyone accepts this usage, so I would like to hear opinions of others.

Thanks. If you said "Her dress dragged the floor" you would be understood but people would think it weird. "Her dress dragged on the floor" would be the natural phrase (at least in the UK. As ever, I cannot speak for what the US think is natural).

@user3856370 Thank you, ChatGPT said "Her dress dragged the floor" was valid, but when I asked again, it said "It's unnatural" :)

Both "Her dress dragged on the floor" and "Her dress dragged the floor" do not make any sense.
